# Make Object in javascript with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to make object in javascript(like class but it is not support for es5/6 on my browser).My goal is get this of function in callback of Jquery.

**Code**

```
var log = e => console.log(e);

$(function(){
    var oop = new _oop();
})

var _oop = function(){
  this.testVariable = 0;
  $.get(url,function(){
    log(this.testVariable);//undefined
  });
}
```

That Variable is point at selector by jquery,I could not thought another ideas,just use "var" instead of "this" could deal this.

----supported 2-13----

To satisfy Browser in low level,I can't use arrow function in this case.
The above one arrow in my code is for dev-mode.

----supported 2-13----
Fixed it.thx for all. 
**Code**

```
var log = e => console.log(e);

$(function(){
    var oop = new _oop();
})

var _oop = function(){
  this.testVariable = 0;
  var cb = function(){log(this.testVariable);}
  $.get(url,cb.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting undefined is because you are trying to use `this` inside an anonymous function.

Try swapping it to use a fat arrow function to maintain the scope of `this`.

```
var log = e => console.log(e);

$(function() {
  var oop = new _oop();
})

var _oop = function() {
  this.testVariable = 0;
  $.get(url, () => {
    log(this.testVariable);
  });
}
```